# Enable Remote Management through terminal only works when I manually click off and on?

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, mojave, ssh

I am able to turn the Remote Management on. But it doesn't work. For it to work the only way is i have to turn it off(after i used terminal command to turn it on) and turn it back again by checking the box. Any reason to why it does this. I tried typing the command to turn it off and on after i turn it on and that does not work either.

Comment: What precise command are you using? I enable remote management via ssh routinely on 10.12 and higher reliably.

Comment: @bmike I am using the command "sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -users admin -privs -all -restart -agent -menu -console" I can run this command when RemoteManagement is unchecked and it turns it on but it won't work. For it to work I have to uncheck it and check again manually.